How to get the character count of a cell to show a "live" counter in the neighboring cell?
I'd like have a character counter for certain fields in a document that my wife sends out to her clients, each of the three fields does have a max but that is not important. Is there a way to create a "live" counter of characters in particular fields?
the characters in the first field would have a running tally in the second
If this is not possible through docs/sheets, a suggestion where it could be done and easily imported into docs would be helpful as well.
I have tried using sheets =len(a2) and that did work as intended once I copied from sheets into docs.
Each of the Position/org and Description fields needs to adhere to a strict criteria and where it is submitted does not track them live

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

A template of your document or similar would help, but if I have understood correctly, you are dealing with a Docs document and not a spreadsheet, the latter only being used to test out possible formulae to insert into the document; is that correct?
If that is indeed the case, I don't know of any built-in functionality that would enable a live character count. Here I propose a non-complete and non-optimal answer using Apps Script, based on the anwer to this other question: Google Docs Add On onEdit.
Why non-optimal? Because the character count will only update every minute or so. For a better solution, but also more complex, see the accepted answer to this other question: How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on.
Now, let's begin. So the goal is to obtain something like this:

First, two assumptions:

you want the character count, including spaces.
the table you have has two columns, the first one containing the text; and one header.

Those two things can very easily be changed in my code and they're only there because your question lacks details, so tell us if the assumptions are wrong.
While waiting for your response, let's look at the few simple steps.

First, open the Apps Script editor: in your document's menu, click on 'Extensions', then 'Apps Script'. A new tab should open.

Then, erase all the "myFunction" stuff. Then, copy-paste the following code:


// The ordinal of the table in the document:
//  1 if it's the first table, 2 if it's the second, etc.
const n = 1;

/**
 * Creates a time-based trigger.
 * 
 * @return {void} Nothing.
 */
function createTimeTrigger() {
  const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('isTableEdited')
                           .timeBased()
                           .everyMinutes(1)
                           .create();
}

/**
 * Updates the character count in the table.
 * 
 * @return {void} Nothing.
 */
function updateCharacterCount() {
  const table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
                           .getBody()
                           .getTables()[n-1];
  for (let i=1; i<table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    const text = table.getCell(i, 0).getText();
    table.getCell(i, 1).setText(text.length);
  }
}

/**
 * Checks if the table's text length has changed, \
 * in which case updates its character count.
 * 
 * @return {void} Nothing.
 */
function isTableEdited () {
  const tableText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
                           .getBody()
                           .getTables()[n-1]
                           .getText();
  if (tableText.length != PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
                                           .getProperty('tableTextLen')) {
    updateCharacterCount();
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
                     .setProperty('tableTextLen', tableText.length);
  }
}


Next, modify the first line of code:

const n = 1;

Instead of 1, put the ordinal in your document of the table in which you want to count the characters. That is: if the table is the first one in the document, leave the 1. If instead there are two other tables before it, so it is table number 3 in the document, change the 1 for a 3.

By now, your window should look something like this:


Click on the arrow in between 'Debug' and 'Execution log' and select createTimeTrigger:


Finally, click on the 'Run' button.

That should be it.
EDIT: as I said, the character count will update every minute or so. However, I have just discovered that it is possible to create the same trigger more than once. So, in theory, you could do that to reduce the idle time to a few seconds. Nevertheless, Google imposes a quota on the use of triggers, that depends on which type of account you have. If you're using a free (Gmail) account, you can probably use two triggers - making it possible for the character count to update every ~30s - , but not many more. If you have a Workspace account (or whatever its name is), you're good to go.

Provided a screenshot in my original post

Yeah well now you provided two different screenshots, showing two different situations.
